# CSS Media Queries regarding max-width property to make 1024px size for Tablet and Desktop

Tags: android, html, css

I am still trying to figure out how media queries work. I have two media queries one targeting **max-width: 1024px** and the other targeting **max-device-width: 1024px** for tablet.

The problem i am facing is that when i test it on my iPAD it skips the **max-device-width: 1024px**  and goes for the **max-width: 1024px**.

My question is how can i write a media query for both Desktop and Tablet for **max width 1024px** ?

The reason i want to have one for desktop and one for tablet at 1024 width is because i need different style for each.

My **CSS** code is below.

```
  @media screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait)
        {#cast1, #cast2, #cast3, #cast4, #cast5, #cast6, #cast7 
          {
            height: 26%;left: 5%;
          }
       } 

  @media screen and (max-width: 1024px)
       {#cast1, #cast2, #cast3, #cast4, #cast5, #cast6, #cast7 
          {
            height: 45%;left: 5%;
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

This set of media queries suitable for the “tablet-and-desktop”

**Mobile**

```
only screen and (min-width: 480px) { ... }
```

**Tablet**

```
only screen and (min-width: 480px) { ... }
only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:768px) { ... }
only screen and (min-width: 768px)  { ... }
```

**Desktop**

```
only screen and (min-width: 992px) { ... }
```

**Huge**

```
only screen and (min-width: 1280px) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

check [Media Queries for Standard Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).    it may be usefull

Comment: Please visit this: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use this media query inside your existing query to make sure its a device with retina resolution

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and ( min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and ( -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) { /* Retina-specific stuff here */ }
```